# C++ Serial Communicating problem with string buffer bytes

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I making C++ Console what can Communicatable with Serial ("COM3") Port.

The Serial has API.

- API

> km.move(int,int)
> print(string) Examples : print('hello, world?')
> km.delay(int)

- Serial's Spec

> BaudRate : 115200
> ByteSize : 8
> StopBits : 1
> Parity : NONE

I tested it with uPyCraft IDE, Putty.

[uPyCraft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4siAR.png)
[Putty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mXc2.png)

it works perfectly, so I make a one C++ Console (Serilib Library Included) and tried to writeFile.

but only sometimes it works fine, mostly it doesn't work.

I think it is buffer size problems, but I don't know how to find and fix them.

I tested it with below code

```
int serialib::writeString(const char *receivedString,int arg)
{
    DWORD dwBytesWritten;
    if(!WriteFile(hSerial,receivedString,arg,&dwBytesWritten,NULL))
        return -1;
    if (!dwBytesWritten)
        return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

```
int main()
{

    serial.openDevice("COM3", 115200,SERIAL_DATABITS_16,SERIAL_PARITY_NONE,SERIAL_STOPBITS_1);
    
    if (serial.isDeviceOpen() != true)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        string str;

        cin >> str;

        serial.writeString(str.c_str(), 32);
        if (!cin) break;

    }
}
```

- The Situations

```
serial.writeString(str.c_str(), 17~32);
km.move(0,20)
```

=> Works fine. (string length is 13) (sec arg should be 17~32) 
Second arg is size, changable 17~32 all was good

```
serial.writeString(str.c_str(), str.size());
km.move(0,20)
```

=> Doesn't work. (string length is 13, same with above.) (sec arg isn't 17~32)
Second arg is 13

```
serial.writeString(str.c_str(), 17~32);
km.move(0,20); -- Included ";"
```

=> Doesn't work. (when ; included, it was stacky, and all stack will work at same time when "The Situations" what Works fine.)

but it was stacky. I mean multiple of `km.move(0,-32767 ~ 32767);` doesn't work but it seems to be stacking.
and when I send a `km.move(0,0~9);` or  `km.move(0,10)` (string size should be 13 and it doesn't care what ";" is included or not, just only get affected with string length. I don't know why)
all of stack what I sended is work at same time.

```
serial.writeString(str.c_str(),17~32);
km.move(0,1);
```

=> Works fine. (That mean string length should be 13)

I think why this problems are causing is serial's bytesize.

because all of "The Situations" are doesn't work when I tried this `serial.openDevice("COM3", 115200,SERIAL_DATABITS_5~7,SERIAL_PARITY_NONE,SERIAL_STOPBITS_1);`

- Result

> DATABITS should be greater than 8.
> string length should be 13.
> bytesize should be 17~32.
> included ";" causing stack

In Putty or uPyCraft, string length doesn't care for work.

Someone help me for communicating with serial port at C++

Comment: You don't really explain what you mean by "doesn't work". What goes wrong? Also, if the string that is input has a length of less than 31 characters, your code (`main` calling `writeString`) accesses the string's buffer out of bounds.

Comment: doesn't work mean => km.move(0.1000) code should move his position to 0, 1000 but it isn't move.

Comment: You write that: "Serial's Spec ...ByteSize : 8", then you also write that you tested bytesize 5-7 and that that didn't work, and finally you have bytesize set to 16 in your code and that doesn't work either. I am confused, why not just set it to 8, like the spec says? For that matter, you say that it works in Putty - so just set it to the size that works there (8?) instead of all this experimenting...

Comment: @Frodyne when bytesize set to 16 also works fine, so i don't remind it. but you right. I'll set it to 8 but it isn't important thing. i hope to find how to send a data to serial likes Putty or uPyCraft.

Answer (score 0):

I think why this problems are causing is serial's bytesize.

Comment: any idea for fix?

Comment: What does 'serial's bytesize" mean?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  i mean databits. : `serial.openDevice("COM3", 115200,SERIAL_DATABITS_16,SERIAL_PARITY_NONE,SERIAL_STOPBITS_1);` <= DATABITS

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).